# Convert Integer to Ascii string in C#

Tags: c#

I want to convert an integer to 3 character ascii string. For example if integer is 123, the my ascii string will also be `"123"`. If integer is 1, then my ascii will be `"001"`. If integer is 45, then my ascii string will be `"045"`. So far I've tried `Convert.ToString` but could not get the result. How?

Comment: Do you want ASCII or text?  A `string` would be far easier to use but is not one byte per character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer for the new question:

You're looking for [`String.PadLeft`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07.aspx). Use it like `myInteger.ToString().PadLeft(3, '0')`. Or, simply use the [`"0"` custom format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx#Specifier0). Like `myInteger.ToString("000")`.

---

Answer for the original question, returning strings like `"0x31 0x32 0x33"`:

```
String.Join(" ",myInteger.ToString().PadLeft(3,'0').Select(x=>String.Format("0x{0:X}",(int)x))
```

Explanation:

- The first `ToString()` converts your integer `123` into its string representation `"123"`.
- `PadLeft(3,'0')` pads the returned string out to three characters using a `0` as the padding character
- Strings are enumerable as an array of `char`, so `.Select` selects into this array
- For each character in the array, format it as `0x` then the value of the character
- Casting the `char` to `int` will allow you to get the ASCII value (you may be able to skip this cast, I am not sure)
- The "X" format string converts a numeric value to hexadecimal
- `String.Join(" ", ...)` puts it all back together again with spaces in between

Comment: Could you explain more on your answer?

Comment: Shoot, I missed you want it padded to a three-character string.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Yes I was just editing my answer to do that. It's done now.

Comment: Sorry guys. I think I ask the wrong question. I've edited my question again. Please review it again , thanks!

Comment: I need to transmit the integer out as ascii string from serial port.

Comment: @maniac84: Please revert your question and ask a new one. The way you've done it now, you've completely invalidated lc's (previously) correct answer.

Comment: @Heinzi No kidding and thanks. I've included both answers here now anyway. Glad I'm paying attention...

Answer (score 10):

```
int myInt = 52;
string myString = myInt.ToString("000");
```

myString is "052" now. Hope it will help

Answer (score 5):

It depends on if you actually want ASCII characters or if you want text.  The below code will do both.

```
int value = 123;
// Convert value to text, adding leading zeroes.
string text = value.ToString().PadLeft(3, '0');
// Convert text to ASCII.
byte[] ascii = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);
```

Realise that .Net doesn't use ASCII for text manipulation.  You can save ASCII to a file, but if you're using `string` objects, they're encoded in UTF-16.